# Error when unwrapping a optional

Tags: ios, swift

In the following code I get an error from xcode saying: **"Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'fahrenheitValue' is a 'let' constant."**

This code sample is from The Big Nerd Ranch Guide for iOS 6th edition. 
A part from not really understanding why the book would be wrong, I understand the meaning of the error but I don't get how I could work around this...

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import UIKit

class ConversionViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var celsiusLabel: UILabel!
    var fahrenheitValue: Measurement<UnitTemperature>? {
        didSet {
            updateCelsiusLabel()
        }
    }
    var celsiusValue: Measurement<UnitTemperature>? {
        if let fahrenheitValue = fahrenheitValue {
            return fahrenheitValue.convert(to: .celsius)
        }else{
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is the code crashing?

Comment: Drop a link to the original code. This is whacky. You are defining the let as a closure, and with the same name as the var above.

Comment: @Rob, isn't that just *optional binding* unwrapping `fahrenheitValue`?

Comment: The line returning an error is : return fahrenheitValue.convert(to: .celsius)
I have no idea where convert is declared but supposed that it was a method of the Measurement type (or protocol)

Comment: Yes it is an optional binding unwrapping...

Comment: Yeah you are right @vacawama, I really like if let (Kotlin which is very similar to Swift does not have it), but when the names are the same on both sides I find it confusing.

Comment: I agree @Rob, I'm not a big fan of that style (using same name for wrapped and unwrapped variable), but it is fairly commonly used.

Comment: Wow silent downvotes are so common now on this site. Really becoming a waste of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is these two lines:

```
if let fahrenheitValue = fahrenheitValue {
    return fahrenheitValue.convert(to: .celsius)
```

You can't call `convert(to:)` on `fahrenheitValue` because `fahrenheitValue` is a constant and `convert(to:)` is trying to modify that constant, hence the error.

The solution is to replace `convert(to:)` to `converted(to:)`. The former doesn't return anything and tries to modify the receiver. The latter creates a new measurement and returns the new value. That is what you want.

```
return fahrenheitValue.converted(to: .celsius)
```

Comment: You are right! And I actually misread the book #shame...
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6):

[rmaddy described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47477302/1271826) the root of the problem, that you're trying to call a mutating function on a local `let` constant, and that you should instead call `converted` to return the converted value rather than trying to mutate the existing value.

But I might suggest simplifying this further with optional chaining:

```
var celsiusValue: Measurement<UnitTemperature>? {
    return fahrenheitValue?.converted(to: .celsius)
}
```

That will automatically return `nil` if `fahrenheitValue` is `nil`, and otherwise will return the value of the `converted(to:)` call.